# Ошибка HTTP: raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, https, request, pytube

Это сам код:

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = input('enter video link: ')
info = YouTube(link)

streams = info['streams'].first()
title = info['title']
author = info['author']
description = info['description']

alling = f"Name:\n{titles}\n"\
         f"Author:\n{authors}\n"\
         f"Description:\n{descriptions}"
print(alling)

VideoDownload = streams.download('"C:/Users/timay/OneDrive/Рабочий стол"')
```

А это ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\timay\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\YT Install Video.py", line 4, in <module>
    info = YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\timay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

Переустановите `pytube` отсюда: [фикс от ssuwani](https://github.com/ssuwani/pytube)

Comment: @Vadik, спасибо за помощь, но переустановка фикса не помогла.
Программа по прежнему выдает ошибку HTTP

Comment: Это все не я :) Это ответ @СlickName :)